# LFN Folder doesn't exist notepad++ edit?

Tags: notepad++

i. Superstition: long file name (LFN) results in "file does not exist" error message.

ii. **This is caused by a quotation error (see accepted answer*1)**!

Reproducing:

Find "AutoHotKeyScript" in RegEdit and alter its sub-key `Edit -> Command -> Default` to "`"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" %1`".

Right-click and click 'edit' in my context menu to open a file in notepad++.

If you're in a directory with a very long name such as `...Program Files\myfile.txt`, the file will not be opened, and the error will come up: "`...Program, file does not exist.  Create it?`".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem occurs because %1 must be put in quotation marks.  In fact, this problem only happens with directory names have spaces in them: it has nothing to do with the length of the path.

Similarly, when editing registry items for file associations, context menu, shell, or shellex, use `"%path-to-program%" "%1"` (with quotes) rather than %1.